# Creating a partian index on a boolean value mongo db

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-.net-driver

I was hoping for some advice in terms of the creating of a partial index on a boolean value `IsDeleted: false`.

Our existing .net service, using the `MongoDb.Driver` makes the call `_dbContext?.Documents?.FindAsync(model => model.Id == id && !model.IsDeleted)` the equivalent which is..

```
db.Documents.find({
                "UserId": NumberLong(1234),
                "IsDeleted": { $ne: true }
            }
```

as example.

The issue is that trying to create the partial index

```
db.Documents.createIndex(
          { "IsDeleted" : 1 },
         { partialFilterExpression: { IsDeleted: { $ne: true } } } 
        );
```

results in the error `unsupported expression in partial index: $not\n    IsDeleted $eq true\n`

I need to create an index on this value. What is the best alternative to the partial index?

Comment: What do you need? `false` is different to `{ $ne: true }`, they behave different for missing value.

Comment: Do most of your documents have `IsDeleted: true`? If not then there may not be much savings or benefit to making the index partial

Answer (score 0):

Partial filter expression doesn't support `$ne`. Use `$eq`, like this:

```
db.Documents.createIndex(
   { "IsDeleted" : 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: { IsDeleted: false } } 
);
```

Check the supported list of expressions [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/).

Answer (score 0):

So just for clarity, and the subsequent answer.
Partial indexes are not supported for the expression `{ IsDeleted: { $ne: true } }` but is supported for `{ IsDeleted: false }`

So updating the C# code to

```
_dbContext?.Documents?.FindAsync(model => model.Id == id && model.IsDeleted == false)
```

as opposed to using `!model.IsDeleted` solves the issue as it translates in to `{ IsDeleted: false }` for the mongo query enabling the use of a partial index

```
db.Documents.createIndex(
 { "IsDeleted" : 1 },
 { partialFilterExpression: { IsDeleted: false } } 
);
```